# How to create a data frame using first record from multiple listings from a list

Tags: r, list

I have a large list of list 'lst' and I would like to pull the first record within the list to a data frame. How can I do that.

I was thinking of using looping to pull the record but stuck at how to stack the records as a df col. I had codes as below:

```
for(i in 1:length(lst)) {
   df[i] <- lst[[i]][[1]][1]
}
```

Current output is not sth that I want. I want `df$record` to store each `lst[[i]][[1]][1]`. Is it a clever to create such data frame?

example lst can be created using code below:

```
lst<- list(list(c("Class A", "86", "Missing")),
     list(c("Class B", "76", "Delay")),
     list(c("Class A", "88", "Missing")),
     list(c("Class D", "Missing", "56")))
```

Comment: @SamR Just added a sample lst.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### base R solution

You can index more than one level with `c()`, i.e.

```r
# They are both "Class A"
lst[[1]][[1]][1] == lst[[c(1,1,1)]]
```

So to pull the first element of the first vector of each sublist we can do:

```r
data.frame(
    record = vapply(lst, \(l) l[[c(1,1)]], character(1))
)
#    record
# 1 Class A
# 2 Class B
# 3 Class A
# 4 Class D
```

#### `tidyverse` solution

If you want a `tidyverse` solution instead, you could also use [`purrr::pluck()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/pluck.html), and provide an accessor function to extract the first element:

```r
library(purrr)
map_chr(
    lst, 
    \(l) pluck(l, 1, \(x) x[1])
)  |>
    dplyr::as_tibble()  |>
    set_names("record")

# # A tibble: 4 × 1
#   record 
#   <chr>  
# 1 Class A
# 2 Class B
# 3 Class A
# 4 Class D
```

Answer (score 3):

```
lst |>
  lapply("[[", 1) |>
  sapply("[", 1) |>
  data.frame(record = _)
#    record
# 1 Class A
# 2 Class B
# 3 Class A
# 4 Class D
```

---

Using this sample data (with the non-syntactic "fancy" quotes from the question replaced with regular quotes).

```
lst<- list(list(c("Class A", "86", "Missing")),
     list(c("Class B", "76", "Delay")),
     list(c("Class A", "88", "Missing")),
     list(c("Class D", "Missing", "56")))
```

Comment: Could you explain more on `|>` and how it pass through to get data frame I want? Many thanks.

Comment: `|>` was introduced a couple years ago in R 4.1.0 as a base R pipe operator similar to `%>%` (popular in the tidyverse). It's useful for chaining commands together in a readable way. Basically `a |> foo()` is the same as `foo(a)`, so my answer above is exactly the same as `data.frame(record = sapply(lapply(lst, "[[", 1) "[", 1))`, but in the answer you can read it top to bottom, here you would have to read it inside to out.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this could help

```
> data.frame(do.call(rbind, unlist(lst, FALSE)))[1]
       X1
1 Class A
2 Class B
3 Class A
4 Class D
```